# Does Clojure STM has a relationship with atom and agent forms?

Tags: clojure, stm

I am looking into the Concurrency programming in Clojure .
http://clojure.org/concurrent_programming

I got to know that **atom**, **ref** and **agent** forms are used to maintain program state.

Only **ref** is used for coordinated updates , so **dosync** macro is used when performing changes.

So it is obvious that STM engine is involved at this point.

Just wanted to be clear about following doubt I have,

> Does Clojure STM has a relationship with atom and agent forms too? or are
>   they just utilized  java.util.concurrent.atomic capabilities ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The STM is related to Agents in that `send`, `send-off` and `send-via`, when called inside a `dosync` block, only take effect once (and if) the transaction successfully commits.

There is no relationship between the STM and Atoms.

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/SergeyStupin/clojure-concurrency-overview?from_search=1 but it says agent is for independent-uncoordinated , and transactions are only for coordinated aren't they?

Comment: @nish1013: Sending messages to an agent is a side-effect. Transactions may be tried multiple times, but you usually want side-effects to happen only once. (In particular, it makes sense to wrap all side-effecting operations (besides modifications of the ref) in a transaction in agents to achieve this behaviour.)

Comment: @Michał Marczyk"Sending messages to an agent is a side-effect" why it is a side effect? please explain. And also if we wrap side effect things in a transaction it could be triggered few times , so what you meant is if we remove refs from particular transaction that will still work fine as it will NEVER re-trigger the transaction. The reason not to re-trigger is there is nothing mutable in such as ref inside it. If we had a ref then it could be change during the transaction so when it comes to commit stage this would be notice hence will re trigger the transaction. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @nish1013: Sorry, my wording was misleading. I didn't mean to suggest to wrap side-effecting operations in transactions generally, but rather that if a side-effect has to be caused in a transaction, it should be wrapped in an agent so that it will only be executed once. Sending a message to an agent is always a side-effect insofar as that the direct return value (the agent itself) is never the result you're really interested in. Either you want the agent to execute actual side-effects (like IO or memory mutation), or you want to dereference it later for the result of an expensive calculation.

Comment: @nish1013: And the "(besides modifications of the ref)" part was not a suggestion to leave such modifications out of transactions, but rather that these don't have to be wrapped in agents because coordinating these specific side-effects is already the core mechanic of transactions.