# What is the Scala equivalent of Clojure's Atom?

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, clojure

Clojure [has an Atom](http://clojure.org/atoms) for [changing state between threads in a synchronous and independent manner](http://clojure.org/concurrent_programming), [that is not part of the STM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18976545/15441). You [use it like this](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/atom):

```
user=> (def my-atom (atom 0))
#'user/my-atom

user=> @my-atom
0

user=> (swap! my-atom inc)
1

user=> @my-atom
1

user=> (swap! my-atom (fn [n] (* (+ n n) 2)))
4
```

My question is: **What is the Scala equivalent of Clojure's Atom?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Shepmaster and @om-nom-nom said, it's a wrapper around `java.util.concurrent.atomic.Atomic...`.

An equivalent wrapper could look like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic._
import scala.annotation.tailrec

object Atom {
  def apply[A](init: A): Atom[A] = new Impl(new AtomicReference(init))

  private class Impl[A](state: AtomicReference[A]) extends Atom[A] {
    def apply(): A = state.get()
    def update(value: A): Unit = state.set(value)
    def transformAndGet(f: A => A): A = transformImpl(f)

    @tailrec private final def transformImpl(fun: A => A): A = {
      val v    = state.get()
      val newv = fun(v)
      if (state.compareAndSet(v, newv)) newv
      else transformImpl(fun)
    }
  }
}
trait Atom[A] {
  def apply(): A
  def update(value: A): Unit
  def transformAndGet(f: A => A): A
}
```

Ex:

```
val myAtom = Atom(0)
myAtom()  // --> 0
myAtom.transformAndGet(_ + 1) // --> 1
myAtom()  // --> 1
myAtom.transformAndGet(_ * 4) // --> 4
```

---

If you use [Scala-STM](http://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/), that functionality is built into STM references, by using the `.single` view:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.stm._
import scala.concurrent.stm._

scala> val myAtom = Ref(0).single
myAtom: scala.concurrent.stm.Ref.View[Int] = 
        scala.concurrent.stm.ccstm.CCSTMRefs$IntRef@52f463b0

scala> myAtom()
res0: Int = 0

scala> myAtom.transformAndGet(_ + 1)
res1: Int = 1

scala> myAtom()
res2: Int = 1

scala> myAtom.transformAndGet(_ * 4)
res3: Int = 4
```

The advantage is that `Ref.apply` will already give you specialised cells for the primitive types, e.g. `Int` instead of `AnyRef` (boxed).

Comment: Here's a Scala implementation matching what Clojure does, including watch support: https://gist.github.com/kirked/32ed1773363dc9b9fb507bc8a07a4db4

Answer (score 5):

It's not Scala-specific, but I'd reach for [AtomicReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) first in Java land. How much of `atom`s functionality do you want/need?

Comment: By the way [atom is implemented atop of atomic reference](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Atom.java)