# How are Atoms implemented in Clojurescript?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, clojure, atomic, clojurescript

In [Clojure to address concurrency](http://clojure.org/atoms) issues [we can use an atom](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/atom) to write:

```
user=> (def my-atom (atom 0))
#'user/my-atom

user=> @my-atom
0

user=> (swap! my-atom inc)
1

user=> @my-atom
1

user=> (swap! my-atom (fn [n] (* (+ n n) 2)))
4
```

We know that this (in the Clojure implementation) is [a wrapper around the Java Atomic object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806074/what-is-the-scala-equivalent-of-clojures-atom/21809866?noredirect=1#21809866).

Interestingly enough, Atoms [are replicated in ClojureScript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure#wiki-concurrent-programming), at a Syntactic level - even though JavaScript runtimes don't have an Atomic reference.

My question is, **How are Atoms implemented in Clojurescript?** Are they just an object Wrapper?

Comment: Javascript is single threaded so I doubt there is much too it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**It just returns and assigns the value.**

In the source
https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/main/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L4081

```
(deftype Atom [state meta validator watches]
  ...
  IDeref
  (-deref [_] state) 
  ...)
```

and
https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/main/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L4110

```
(defn atom
  "Creates and returns an Atom ..."
  ([x] (Atom. x nil nil nil))
  ([x & {:keys [meta validator]}] (Atom. x meta validator nil)))
```

check the implementation of `swap!` and `reset!` you will find out:

`(set! (.-state a) new-value)`

then , go to https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/3bb97961cbc958aeaeac506222dc7b9dcb0e9fc1/src/clj/cljs/compiler.clj#L771 the `set!`, you will find the compiler just emits an 'assignment statement':

```
(defmethod emit* :set!
  [{:keys [target val env]}]
  (emit-wrap env (emits target " = " val)))
```

Comment: I think watchers implementation is more interesting.